# Is there any way that I can redirect to other site when someone access to a particular site?

Tags: url-redirection

On my company's computer, someone play the internet game so I want to deny the site and redirect to another site.
Or If someone access the game site redirect to other site right off on computer sestimg

Comment: .... there are _lots_ of game sites on the internet.  Including some in places you wouldn't expect - like [search engines](https://www.bing.com/fun).  Banning them as one-offs is unlikely to remain practical.  The usual thing in a corporate environment, and one that also deals with other threats, is a proxy firewall (usually a subscription device/service) - would one of those be reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that, but here are a  few, by order of complexity and effectiveness :

1. Edit their `hosts` file.
2. Add the targeted domain to you internal DNS server as an authoritative zone.
3. Setup a proxy server in your network and configure it to redirect the targeted domain. You will also need to prevent outgoing http/https requests to the outside